# Rails 4 Bootstrap 3 Nav Collapse expands but won't re-collapse

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

The collapse expands just fine, but won't re-collapse. I think maybe the multiple Bootstrap gems that I have installed might be conflicting. Is there an easy way to test that?

This app has been around since it was a Rails 3 app and since upgrading to 4 last year it works great, except for this.

My gemfile:

```
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.2.8'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.32.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.2"
gem 'faker', '1.2.0'
gem 'auto_html'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.0.11'
```

My navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="row header_row1">
    <div class="header_title">
      theTens
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to (image_tag current_user.image(:small), class: "header_pic"), current_user %>
        <%= link_to 'New Review',  new_pin_path, class: "btn btn-danger new_review" %>
      <% else %> 
        <%= link_to "Sign Up Now!", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-large sign_up_button" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row header_row2">  
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tens_nav">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tens_nav"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="home">
            <%= link_to root_path do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
            <% end %>  
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> theLists 
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to 'Tens 2013',  tens2013_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Tens 2012',  tens2012_path %></li>
            </ul>  
          <li>    
            <%= link_to 'theReviewers',  reviewers_path, class: "header_text" %>
          </li>
          <li>    
            <%= link_to 'theComments',  comments_board_path %>
          </li>
          <li>    
            <%= link_to 'theStats',  stats_path %>
          </li> 
          <li><%= link_to 'theBlog',  blog_path %></li>
        </ul>  
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> theMenu 
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-toggle"><%= link_to 'Add +',  new_pin_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile',  edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Logout',  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>  
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to 'Login',  new_user_session_path %></li>
            <% end %>  
          </ul>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Here's my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.masonry.min.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

Comment: inspect your source and make sure that all JS files (jQuery, Bootstrap) load only once, also verify that the BS version of the CSS code JS code is at least the same.

Comment: @BassJobsen When I inspect the source I only have styles.css jquery.js and bootstrap-collapse.js that loads, so I don't think that's it. Can you explain further what you mean by verify that the BS version of the JS code should be the same? thx

Comment: Form the docs: Collapse requires the transitions plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap. I mean that you should not use the Javascript from BS version 3.1 with the CSS of BS version 3.2

Comment: That worked! I needed to update my rails gem, which led to me needing to update my will_paginate gem, which caused other issues. Once I resolved those issues I updated the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and now it works. If you want to enter an answer below I'll accept it. thx again

Comment: glad it works. I think this question should be closed